# How to make $ not part of a symbol in tcl-mode?

Tags: major-mode, syntax

Recently I found out about `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` but in tcl it's rather useless, because when dereferencing a variable the `$` is part of the symbol and so the `symbol-at-point` `$var` does not match `${var}` or `var`.

In the following example code look at each symbol with `M-: (symbol-at-point)`

```
set var 1
puts "var = $var"
puts "${var}23"
```

Funny enough the syntax highlighting clearly differentiates between the symbol and the syntactic character. In perl-mode this is working well.

So the question is: what has to be changed in *tcl.el* (the one that comes with emacs 24.5.1) to exclude `$` from  the symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of searching I found that syntactic elements like parentheses, comment delimiters, characters that can be used for syntactic symbols and others are managed by a *syntax table* (look it up in the *elisp reference manual*) .  With the help of `describe-syntax` I compared the syntax tables for *perl-mode* and *tcl-mode*. In *perl-mode* the character `$` is given the class *character quote* but in *tcl-mode* it is class *symbol*.

So the solution is, to give `$` another class than *symbol* but I think, *character quote* is not the right one, because the manual states about this class:

> Characters used to quote the following character so that it loses
>   its normal syntactic meaning.  This differs from an escape
>   character in that only the character immediately following is ever
>   affected.

AFAIK the class *expression prefix* is far better suited:

> Characters used for syntactic operators that are considered as part
>   of an expression if they appear next to one.  In Lisp modes, these
>   characters include the apostrophe, ‘'’ (used for quoting), the
>   comma, ‘,’ (used in macros), and ‘#’ (used in the read syntax for
>   certain data types).

### tl;dr

The following form changes the tcl syntax table after it is defined:

```
(with-eval-after-load "tcl"
  (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "'" tcl-mode-syntax-table))
```

`with-eval-after-load` was introduced in 24.4 for older version, there is the function `eval-after-load` (see: [What is “with-eval-after-load” in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880139/what-is-with-eval-after-load-in-emacs-lisp))

Answer (score 1):

Adding a hook that modifies the syntax of `$` as suggested by a FIXME comment in [`tcl.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/8a9ba4d67bfb3b9cf96cff2917fec1fa7a168724/lisp/progmodes/tcl.el#L248) seems to work:

```el
(defun my-tcl-modify-dollar-syntax ()
  (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "'" tcl-mode-syntax-table))

(add-hook 'tcl-mode-hook #'my-tcl-modify-dollar-syntax)
```

Comment: You have beaten me by some minutes ;-)  I don't think it's necessary to add this to the hook, cause the syntax table is a normal global variable, isn't it?

Comment: @UweKoloska: I bet you're right!